# How to get std::optional support in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++17, libc++, stdoptional

I'm trying to use std::optional in an Xcode 12.0 Mac OS project. I'm getting the error:
No template named 'optional' in namespace 'std'

```
#include <optional>

std::optional<int> o;
```

My settings are (I need libc++ for project):

[image]

Comment: That's very odd; I don't have Xcode 12 installed, but I do have the apple command-line tools for Catalina (Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)) and your code compiles w/o error for me.

Comment: `clang++ -std=c++17 -c so.cpp`

Comment: the `<optional>` header was added in Xcode11. See the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11-release-notes)

Comment: Have you looked at the build log - specifically, at the commands passed to the compiler? I know your screenshot shows you've selected C++17; can you verify that that is being passed to the compiler? Also, have you tried my command-line from above?

Comment: @MarshallClow Thanks for your input.  I'm building a plugin from a template project and after more careful inspection I noted and removed '-std=gnu++11' under "Other C++ flags".

Answer (score 3):

The version of libc++ that Apple ships as part of Xcode 12 (and 11) includes support for many C++17 features, including `optional`.  See the Xcode 11 [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11-release-notes).

The text in Xcode that says that libc++ "supports C++11" is in contrast to the standard library (libstdc++ v 4.2.1) that Apple used to ship - that did not support C++11. It does not mean that it only supports C++11 to the exclusion of C++14/17/20/etc.

The OP mentioned in a comment that he had a `-std=gnu++11` in the "Other flags" that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) type is a C++17 feature. Although you are compiling with C++17 in your settings, look closer at the standard library version. It states that the version you are using it only supports up to C++11.

Upgrade your library to use `std::optional`.

Alternatively you can *try* to `#include <experimental/optional>` and see if your library has `std::experimental::optional` available.

Comment: That's not true; the libc++ that Apple ships supports many things beyond C++11

Comment: @MarshallClow Look at the screenshot. It literally says "LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support". I have little doubt that there is a libc++ version that supports C++17. But the one OP is using appears not to.

Comment: the libc++ project was begun (back in 2010) to provide a standard library implementation to support C++11 - as opposed to libstdc++ 4.2.1 (which is what Apple was shipping at the time, which did not support C++11).  I believe that's where that text came from. In any case, I assure you that Apple does not ship (today, or any time since about 2015) a C++11-only standard library implementation.

Comment: @MarshallClow Okay, I'd like to believe your assurance. Given the information presented by OP, it just looks very much as if an outdated library was to blame. And so far I don't have a better theory --- and also I don't own an Apple on which to test this.

Comment: @bitmask <experimental/optional> is not in the Xcode 12 release.  Also the standard library version, although the name says "c++ 11 support" it purportedly has been updated to support C++17.  https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/114246. Xcode 12 is the latest Xcode.

Comment: @bitmask I'm building a plugin from a template project and after more careful inspection I noted and removed '-std=gnu++11' under "Other C++ flags".  bit mask if you update your answer to clarify that "LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support" also means versions up to C++17 and to check "Other C++ flags" isn't overriding I'll accept it as the answer.  And experimental is no longer used.  Thanks.

Comment: @bhartsb No, Marshall Clow called it. I'd recommend accepting [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63985111/430766).